# Get the index number of ArrayList Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist

I wanted to know the index number of an array so tried as shown below.

```
val countryCodeList = arrayListOf(*resources.getStringArray(R.array.countryCodes))
val countryIndex = countryCodeList.indexOf("+1")
```

And it only returns true(0) & false(-1). If string `"+1"` locates on the 4th row of the list, I want it to return 3 for the result.

How can I receive the index number of an arrayList?

> Log

```
array : [+82, Korea]
result: -1
==================================================
array : [+60, Malaysia]
result: -1
==================================================
array : [+1, USA]
result: 0
```

Comment: can you please share that countryCodes array. I guess "+1" is at index 0

Comment: @AmitBalani Please take a look at the edited posting. It only returns -1 or 0.

Comment: By looking at this, i can say it's arraylist of arrays. You can't check it with indexOf. Please can you share that countryCodes array which is stored in your res file, not whole file but some of it's items.

Comment: if your string contains only country codes .. this should work .. pls edit your question and add the values of all Strings ..

Answer (score 1):

Issue might be, you are not assigning string items to array properly.

Try below code, it should work

**Your resource file should like**

```
`<resources>
<string name="app_name">Sample</string>
    <string-array name="countryCodes">
        <item name="KR">@string/korea_number</item>
        <item name="MY">@string/malaysia_number</item>
        <item name="AU">@string/indonesia_number</item>
        <item name="SG">@string/singapore_number</item>
        <item name="CA">@string/us_number</item>
        <item name="NZ">@string/new_zealand_number</item>
    </string-array>

<string name="korea_number">+92</string>
<string name="malaysia_number">+91</string>
<string name="indonesia_number">+99</string>
<string name="singapore_number">+93</string>
<string name="us_number">+94</string>
<string name="new_zealand_number">+98</string> </resources>`
```

**On your activity file or fragment file you can access like this**

`val countryCodeList = arrayListOf(*resources.getStringArray(R.array.countryCodes)) val countryIndex = countryCodeList.indexOf("+99")`

```
`println("countryIndex $countryIndex")`
```

if you want, you can replace appropirate country codes.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was about the string. I posted my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
val countries = resources.getStringArray(R.array.countryCodes)
val index = countries.indexOf("+1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I share my final solution for anyone in need.
It only returned 0 or -1 because my string was not exactly same as the value on the array list.

> **Solution**

I used `filter` function and called the value which contains my string.
Then, I used `replace` and deleted `"["` and `"]"`.
Finally, I could have the exactly same string as the value on array list and now it gives me the index number of the string that I am looking for.